# Smart table pagination issue while loading data from local storage

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

In ng2-smart table

```
'this.source.setPaging(pageNum, 25, true);'
```

is not working, if we load data from local storage. Data is loading as expected, but

> setpaging

is not working, we want to retain page number after reloading the page, is there any other ways to retain the page number when reloading in ng2-smart table via angluar/typescript ?